# Add an incremental row to an Oracle Database Table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an oracle database with 6 million records in it. I need to add an incremental column to the database and have it numbered from 1 to 6 million. I'm sure there is an easy SQL method to do this, or perhaps a way to have the database number it for me.

Would someone kindly assist me in doing this, in such a way that a novice can figure it out using SQL Developer?

I tried several methods, but I am new to this, so I was unsure of how to proceed.  A simple SQL statement would be helpful.

Comment: I tried...
ALTER TABLE Payroll ADD (id NUMBER);

UPDATE Payroll
SET id = ROWNUM;

However it executed too quickly, said it was successful...  and I do not see anything changed.

Comment: Did you commit the transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can add an `IDENTITY` column to the table and the database will generate the numbers for you (and will number any future columns).

For example:

If you have the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (name) AS
SELECT 'Alice' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Betty' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Carol' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Debra' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Emily' FROM DUAL;
```

Then you can add an `IDENTITY` column using:

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD id NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY;
```

And the table contains:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

| NAME | ID |
| --- | --- |
| Alice | 1 |
| Betty | 2 |
| Carol | 3 |
| Debra | 4 |
| Emily | 5 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QB0I_rBG)

Comment: This solution will update existing rows without any tricks and, unlike others, will allow future rows to be automatically numbered in consistent way. It will also handle pending modifications consistently (which are performed while update process is taking place)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I had originally tried the above answer, but for some odd reason it actually increments some lines incorrectly.  Your answer worked perfectly.  I had to upgrade my Oracle database recently to v12, so I actually had to start over and implemented your method instead.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you already have that column in a table, don't you? Let's presume its name is `SEQ`. Then you'd just

```
update your_table set seq = rownum;
```

Simple enough?

Comment: I don't think I can find a shorter solution than this one.

Answer (score 1):

Add the incremental_id column:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD (incremental_id NUMBER);
```

Update the column with incremental values:

```
UPDATE my_table SET incremental_id = ROWNUM;
```

Replace my_table with your table's name and execute the statements in SQL Developer.

Comment: I could have sworn I tried that...  apparently yours worked perfectly though.  Thanks.

I think I found my error...  I named it 'ID' and I am assuming that is an invalid/reserved name.

Comment: ORA-30036: unable to extend segment by 8 in undo tablespace 'UNDO'??

Comment: ORA-30036 - that's a dba issue you should ask at dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Stephen-Developer `ID` is not a reserved word and is not a problem to use as an identifier.

Comment: fyi...  I had to undo this one as the answer.  I can't say why, but for some odd reason when I did a check on the database, it appeared to either skip numbers, or perhaps it put the numbers in an unsynchronous way.  Whatever happened, some numbers were skipped and it actually incremented some lines by 3 or 4.  I went with the identifier column below.